# Haskell - "lacks an accompanying binding" for recursive function

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
tempFunc :: Int-> Int-> Int
tempFunc x y
    | y == 0 = 0
    | x `mod` y == 0 = y + tempFunc x (y-1)
    | otherwise = y-1
```

Its purpose is to recursively sum all the factors of a number together. I want to eliminate the need for the second parameter `y` (since `y` is equal to `x`), so I implemented the function in the following way

```
tempFunc :: Int-> Int-> Int
sumFactor num = tempFunc num num
    where
        tempFunc x y
        ...
```

But I get the following error:

```
The type signature for ‘tempFunc’ lacks an accompanying binding
```

This type of error, I noticed, arises when the type definitions are incorrect. But I cannot figure out what is wrong with my type definitions, since the first excerpt works.

Comment: Before getting flagged once more, I would like people to see that I edited my question. I do believe it fits within the guidelines now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type signature for a function has to be in the same scope as the function itself. If you want to add a type signature to a function inside a `where` clause (which is usually not done, but sometimes makes sense) you have to put it in the `where` clause itself:

```
sumFactor num = tempFunc num num
    where
        tempFunc :: Int-> Int-> Int
        tempFunc x y
            | y == 0 = 0
            | x `mod` y == 0 = y + tempFunc x (y-1)
            | otherwise = y-1
```

Comment: @Bolboa: okay, made the change